# File upload dialog file picker groups files by sizes

Tags: google-chrome, file, dialog

When I use the file upload dialog to pick files it only shows some files
[image]

In this example it says "from 10KB to 100 KB" how do I stop grouping files by size? I generally like to browse by age not grouped by size.

How do I stop grouping by size?

Answer (score 1):

The drop menu, top left, can set by several criteria, including by Size.

[image]

If you set that to None, then you can quickly sort by any column header by clicking it.